# 100% width table cell

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I have this table layout. I want to align the whole content to the right. So i'm using one cell with `width: 100%;`. Usually everything looks good and nice.
But there is something, which i don't understand. If the content in cell, which has colspan, becomes bigger than normal cell in this column (you can test this by clicking `Click to test button`), it brakes whole layout.
This happens on Chrome, Safari 4 and 5, IE8, but on Opera, FF and IE7 is OK.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { width: 100%; }
        table td { border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; }
        .delimiter { width: 100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Row 1</label></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Field 1" id="field1" size="25"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Click to test" onclick="var o = document.getElementById('field2'); o.size = o.size == 25 ? 50 : 25;"></td>
                <td class="delimiter">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Row 2</label></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="field2" value="Field 2" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not surprised when you said it worked in some browsers and not others. Welcome to the real world of developing a web app. I haven't gone down into the nitty gritty of checking why browsers are refreshing their layouts differently, as i've learned that it can be a black hole of time. Instead i put forth the following solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table { width: 100%; }
    table td { border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; }
    .delimiter { width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Row 1</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="delimiter">
                <table><tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="Field 1" id="field1" size="25" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Click to test" onclick="var o = document.getElementById('field2'); o.size = o.size == 25 ? 50 : 25;" /></td>
                    <td class="delimiter">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Row 2</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table><tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="field2" value="Field 2" size="25" /></td>
                    <td class="delimiter">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's not the prettiest solution, but as raw html it does work. Tested in Chrome and IE10.

Answer (score -2):

Use W3C standards to be more save with crossbrowser coding. Beste solution for javascript code crossbrowser safty is to user jQuery. It's even more handy for this kind of tools/functionalities.

Comment: Well, I can't use jQuery, because I will have to rewrite whole application then :)
  
P.S. What do you mean 'Use W3C standards'?

Comment: jQuery, although a very popular and widely implemented library is not the be all and end of of front end design. Its completely acceptable to choose not to use the library.